# Android application installs but not launches

Tags: android, eclipse

Before labeling this as a duplicate, please read. I have successfully installed an Android application I developed on Eclipse on to two different platforms: one emulator (Blue Stacks) and one actual device. Like I said, the app installs just fine on both platforms, but it doesn't appear on the list of apps that can be launched. When I go to settings, I can see the app on the list of installed applications, and it lets me uninstall it, but not open it. I've spent hours trying every remedy online, but nothing works. My app is only one activity, so it should be simple, but this is the first app I've developed. I'll attach my manifest xml file below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.teamjava.theultimatetipcalculator"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.teamjava.theultimatetipconverter.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActivity" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try using the same package name for the app and location of your activity.

You have:

```
package="com.teamjava.theultimatetipcalculator"

android:name="com.teamjava.theultimatetipconverter.MainActivity"
```

Try

```
package="com.teamjava.theultimatetipcalculator"

android:name="com.teamjava.theultimatetipcalculator.MainActivity"
```

or

```
package="com.teamjava.theultimatetipconverter"

android:name="com.teamjava.theultimatetipconverter.MainActivity"
```

*EDIT* -

Also try placing the intent filter inside the activity. This is how my manifest looks on all my apps

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.exampleapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Good catch but for some reason the problem still persists. Thank you.

Comment: try the suggestion in my edit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActivity" />
```

to:

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to make any change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your console in Eclipse?  Sometimes, your program can compile fine, but display errors in the console on startup.

In Eclipse.  Window - show view - Console

Comment: No errors on the console.